# Responsive design with CSS Grids

Tags: css, grid

I'd like to have responsive version to this code.

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
        "navigation-bar content content content";
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.navigation-bar {
    grid-area: navigation-bar;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #1a1b20;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    background-color: #202127;
}

<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

What I have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
    }

    .navigation-bar {
    }

    .content {
    }
}
```

I'd like to have `navigation-bar` on the top of the website and `content` below it.

It means:

1. `grid-template-columns` should be `1fr`
2. height of `navigation-bar` should be about 25vh

But I don't know, what `grid-template-rows` should be.

It depends on `content`, but if there is no content in `content`, it should fill whole screen (`navigation-bar` and `content` is a rest).

May you help me with responsive desige, please?

EDIT:

On mobile phone:

[image]

Comment: Use flexbox instead of grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the base styles using columnar `flex` and then a use `grid` when the screen is larger than `600px`. Note that in mobile, `.content` uses `flex-grow: 1`, which means it will fill all the remaining vertical space.

```css
.navigation-bar {
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: #1a1b20;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #202127;  
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "navigation-bar content content content";
  }

  .navigation-bar {
    grid-area: navigation-bar;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .content {
    grid-area: content;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">navbar</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgnkws03/3/)

Comment: I am sorry, I probably explained that bad. I added an image to my main post.

Comment: @JohnDoe I don't see the image you've mentioned but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh. The `navigation-bar` should be on top of the website, I mean `width: 100vw; height: 15vh` and the rest of the website should be `content`. And this layout will be on mobile phone.

Comment: @JohnDoe You may need to refresh the page. It's working this way now. View full screen and adjust the browser width to see.

Comment: I probably need `navbar` to `position: sticky`, because when I give `content` too many texts and I scroll down, `navbar` stays up. But simply `position: sticky` to `navbar` class doesn't work. May you help me with that?

Comment: @JohnDoe Create a new question and I'm sure someone can help with that.